# rearranging differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have an equation $$\dfrac{d^2h}{dt^2}+\dfrac{\rho AC_d}{2m}\left(\dfrac{dh}{dt}\right)^2=g$$

How can I rearrange for $t$?

- I'm trying to find an equation for an object dropped in water which sinks to the seabed, which allows me to easily calculate the time taken for the object to reach the bottom. I think this is the equation I need but I don't know how to rearrange for $t$.

Comment: This is (I presume) an equation of motion, describing the behaviour of $h$ as a function of time. We're going to need a little more information to get the time taken to reach the bottom.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I think that you are correct in your pressumption. here's the information that I have:

Answer (score 1):

$$
\dfrac{d^2h}{dt^2}+\dfrac{\rho AC_d}{2m}\left(\dfrac{dh}{dt}\right)^2=g
$$
standard method
$$
\dfrac{d^2h}{dt^2} = h'\dfrac{d}{dh}h' = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dh}h'^2
$$
this leads to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dh}h'^2 + \dfrac{\rho AC_d}{2m}h'^2 = g
$$
thus we get
$$
h'^2\mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{\rho AC_d}{m}dh} = \int g \mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{\rho AC_d}{m}dh} dh
$$

$$
\mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{\rho AC_d}{m}dh} = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\rho AC_d}{m}h}
$$

$$
h'^2 \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\rho AC_d}{m}h} = \frac{gm}{\rho AC_d}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\rho AC_d}{m}h} + \lambda \implies h'^2 = \frac{gm}{\rho AC_d}+\lambda \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\rho AC_d}{m}h}
$$
assuming that it stops when the object comes to the bottom i.e. $h = 0 \implies h' = 0$ as
$$
0 = \frac{gm}{\rho AC_d}+\lambda \implies \lambda = -\frac{gm}{\rho AC_d}
$$
therefore
$$
h' = \sqrt{\frac{gm}{\rho AC_d}}\sqrt{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\rho AC_d}{m}h}}
$$
thus
$$
\int_{h(0)}^{h(t)} \frac{dh}{\sqrt{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\rho AC_d}{m}h}}} = \sqrt{\frac{gm}{\rho AC_d}}t
$$